# How to use "grep -wvf" to get differences between two files

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, grep, command

I got two files.

```
-> cat firstfile
sample-dev
sample-dev-auth

-> cat secondfile
sample-dev
sample-dev-auth
sample-dev-temp
```

and then I execute `grep -wvf firstfile secondfile`, which I know will give me differences between two files, so I thought output will be `sample-dev-temp`, but NO

```
-> grep -wvf firstfile secondfile
```

nothing shows up.

And I tried `grep -wf` which opposite to `-wvf`, I though it would show me

```
sample-dev
sample-dev-auth
```

but still No, it's like

```
-> grep -wf firstfile secondfile
```

output:

**sample-dev**

**sample-dev**-auth

**sample-dev**-temp

it returned all items and highlighted the similar part.

why it's working like this? And how to get the result I want？

Comment: You're probably looking for `comm` or `diff`, not `grep`.

Comment: @Shawn yeah I checked `comm` and `diff` out, it will do but I want a simple  clean formatted output like grep gives me as input for the result of the whole script

Comment: Try `grep -wvf secondfile firstfile`.

Comment: `echo sample-dev-auth | grep -w sample-dev` prints `sample-dev-auth`.  The `-w` option looks for word boundaries, and a dash is a word boundary.  So the first line in `firstfile` is bound to match all three lines in `secondfile` — hence nothing gets printed.  You need a command with a different definition of 'word' — or maybe use the `-x` (exact) match option instead of `-w`.  (Casual experimentation with `grep -xvf firstfile secondfile` produces the wrong result; it ain't that easy, it seems.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `grep -wf firstfile secondfile` reads pattern from `firstfile` and searches for them in `secondfile`. When I execute `grep -wf firstfile secondfile` I get the following output:

**sample-dev**
**sample-dev-auth**
**sample-dev**-temp

Please note that my output differs from yours. Let me explain the behaviour of grep with my output.
The pattern found in `secondfile` (marked as bold) are all listed in `firstfile`. This is what `grep` should be used for, searching for pattern.

If we add the parameter `-v` to the grep command the result will be inverted (by line). Which means that all lines will be displayed which do not have any match. Therefore we have an empty result because all lines match. We can verify this behaviour by adding additional data to `secondfile`, e.g.

```
$ echo hello >> secondfile 
$ grep -wvf firstfile secondfile
hello
```

Only *hello* is displayed because no pattern in `firstfile` matches here.

Having said that `grep` is not the tool you should use in this scenario. You can use the `diff` tool which is for finding differences in files, e.g.:

```
$ diff firstfile secondfile
2a3
> sample-dev-temp
```

Please have a look at the manual of `diff`. There are many options for customization.